# thingsboard send multiple data to device with http api with curl in cmd

Tags: curl, thingsboard, httpapi

i am trying to send two number to thingsboard iot platform.
send one data is like this :
curl -v POST --data "{"photoresistor":10}" https://thingsboard.cloud/api/v1/nIjlT58Xo81AdU2Pwymm/telemetry --header "Content-Type:application/json"

but i do not know how to send two data to thingsboard .
in my search i saw this

curl -v -X POST --data "{"temperature":42,"humidity":73}" https://demo.thingsboard.io/api/v1/ABC123/telemetry --header "Content-Type:application/json"

form https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/

but any device should have one $ACCESS_TOKEN . and  i can not use above command with two data "{"temperature":42,"humidity":73}" .
because every device need one ACCESS_TOKEN.

please help me to solve this problem.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Thingsboard CE then you will need to get creative if you don't want to use access tokens. Possibly look at AWS lambda functions to act as a middle-man to forward messages.

If you're using Thingsboard PE then instead of posting to the device directly using it's ACCESS_TOKEN, you can use Integrations & Data Converters.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to achieve this with ThingsBoard CE. You could use the MQTT Gateway API:

"Gateway API provides the ability to exchange data between multiple devices and the platform using single MQTT connection."

[https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/gateway-mqtt-api/#:~:text=Gateway%20API%20provides%20the%20ability%20to%20exchange%20data,below%20is%20used%20by%20ThingsBoard%20open-source%20IoT%20Gateway](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/gateway-mqtt-api/#:%7E:text=Gateway%20API%20provides%20the%20ability%20to%20exchange%20data,below%20is%20used%20by%20ThingsBoard%20open-source%20IoT%20Gateway).

Still ACCESS_TOKEN is needed, but only one for the Gateway. You can publish messages of multiple devices in a single connection. Each device is identified by it's name. Also not existing devices are created automatically.

Comment: Can you bring an example ?

Comment: General MQTT examples in the documention:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/

1. First create the Gateway device (Set "Is gateway" to true)
2. Copy ACCESS_TOKEN of Gateway device
3. Send data via MQTT (example shows mosquitto, also many clients available for e.g. Python)

**Important**: 
Use topic v1/gateway/telemetry and Gateway ACCESS_TOKEN.
Provide Device Name in Payload (https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/gateway-mqtt-api/#:%7E:text=Gateway%20API%20provides%20the%20ability%20to%20exchange%20data,below%20is%20used%20by%20ThingsBoard%20open-source%20IoT%20Gateway)